# Are execute statements not rolled back on exception?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I have a migration where I'm changing the character set for a MySQL table, from latin1 to utf-8. After that, I'm trying to alter the objects in some way. I'd like that if an object fails to save to rollback the database, including the character set change. Here's my code:

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE posts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf-8;"
  posts = Post.find_each do |post|
    # modify post.content
    post.save!
  end
  raise "rollback"
end
```

I am doing a `raise "rollback"` because I want to test and make sure that the migration works succesfully. However, if I do a `show create table posts` after the migration rolled back, I see that it's character set is still utf-8. Are execute statements not wrapped in the transaction?

Comment: All DDL statements perform an implicit commit, you cannot roll them back.

Answer (score 3):

`alter table` performs an [implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html) in mysql. You cannot rollback an `alter`.

Comment: Very strange though ... it seems that even my post objects remain modified. Before running the migration, I have 280 posts that need change. After running it, I have 0 ... even though I throw an exception to trigger the rollback. Do you know what happens?

Comment: There is no transaction to rollback in your example

Comment: Aren't Rails migrations ran in transactions by default?